# Почему не сериализуется SortedDictionary?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Почему не сериализуется SortedDictionary?

```
public static SortedDictionary<int, Tower> DICT_TOWER = new SortedDictionary<int, Tower>();
```

> SerializationException: Type System.Collections.Generic.RBTree is not marked as Serializable.
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryCommon.CheckSerializable (System.Type type, ISurrogateSelector selector, StreamingContext context) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary/BinaryCommon.cs:119)
>   System

Так сериализуется без ошибок:

```
 public static Dictionary<int, Tower> DICT_TOWER = new Dictionary<int, Tower>();
```

Словарь находится внутри data

```
BinaryFormatter bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            bformatter.Binder = new ClassBinder();//Здесь мы обучаем сериализатор работать с нашим классом
            MemoryStream streamReader = new MemoryStream();
            bformatter.Serialize(streamReader, data);//Cериализуем
```

Comment: Скорее всего у вас в классе есть атрибут, который не сериализуется, например event.... соответственно его надо пометить как несериализуемый... что-то типа `[field:NonSerializedAttribute()]
public event EventHandler BrazierCuttoffChanged;`

Comment: Атрибут какого класса? 

Класс Tower нормально сериализуется внутри Dictionary<int, Tower>

Comment: Надо смотреть весь класс, в котором это поле. и как вы все делаете...., т.е. как в тот же `data` и что пихаете...... но  проблема не в `SortedDictionary`

Comment: Может быть, проблема только на Mono?

Comment: @VladD точно в Mono, http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/mono-bugs/2008-August/078574.html. Похоже так и не пофиксили за 8(!) лет.